# Formula to select certain people only

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a spresdsheet in google sheets and use the following formula

```
=QUERY('Main Data'!A2:U,"select B, sum(J), sum(E),count(E), sum(F), count(F), sum(G), count(U), 
WHERE A IS NOT NULL

AND O>= DATE """&text(H2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&""" 
AND O<= DATE """&text(H3,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"""    
group by B
order by sum(J) desc
```

The problem is that there are 10 x sales peoples names in column B, and I only want to select certain people, but I cant get it to work.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add some sample data and the corresponding expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Insert additional conditions in the `where` clause, like this:

```
=query( 
  'Main Data'!A2:U, 
  "select B, sum(J), sum(E),count(E), sum(F), count(F), sum(G), count(U) 
   where A is not null 
   and (B = 'Jane Smith' or B = 'Dweezil Mackay' or B = 'Jill Jones') 
   and date " & text(H2, "'yyyy-MM-dd'") & "<= O and O <= date " & text(H2, "'yyyy-MM-dd'") & "
   group by B 
   order by sum(J) desc 
  ", 0 
)
```

Note that there must be no comma after the final expression in the `select` clause, and that the `headers` parameter should always be specified to avoid surprises (here, it is `0`.)

See the [query language help page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Language_Syntax).